# what is "android" in xml file? Where does definition of Button come from?

Tags: android, xml, button

We start xml file with some layout. Within that layout we create our views like `Button`, `TextView` etc. But how does the system know what are `Button` and `TextView`? I mean we are not importing anything. Moreover inside `Button`, we write `android:layout_width = "wrap_content"` what is `android` in this? Since it is inside Button why can't we write `layout_width = "wrap_content"` directly?

Comment: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` refers to the android xml name space. that is why you have android prefix. Its the same if you have Custom Attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **developer.android.com** `android:` defines the Android namespace. This attribute should always be set to "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android".

`xmlns:android` is for identification that this xml is used for android, not for other function.

Namespaces uniquely identify code/libraries. If I write an api that uses all the same names and such as the android api the only way to distinguish between my api and android api is to use the android namespace, or mine. Read [XML NameSpace](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp)

Check out [tutorial on namespaces](http://www.sitepoint.com/xml-namespaces-explained/)

Comment: Is Button inside android namespace like a child element? and layout_width is common to many views. Is it defined for every child element inside android namespace? Thanks!

Comment: Yes some common property of the views are defined inside the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

It is called as the namespace. At the top of every XML file you will have this line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` That's where the namespace `android` comes from

Answer (score 1):

XML is a document language. The meaning of the elements is given to them by the compiler.

When you compile the XML file using Android's resource compiler, it imparts meaning to them.

The prefix `android:` establishes the namespace of the tag that follows it.

You can learn more about XML namespaces here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp